# Open a card example from framer motion homepage

Tags: reactjs, animation, next.js, framer-motion, scroll-snap

I'm facing a tough issue with a grid container that uses scroll snapping. The layout malfunctions when I expand an element using layoutId. This only happens when scroll snapping is active. (I am using **Framer motion** for animation)

I've spent the last 48 hours trying to solve this without success. If anyone is willing to lend their expertise, I'm open to providing compensation for your time and effort.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

The code is self-contained and can be copy-pasted into a component. This makes it easy for anyone to reproduce the error and analyze the problem firsthand.

What im trying is to make this example from framer motion homepage: https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/905, but inside a scroll snapping grid container.

```
import Image from "next/image"

import { useCallback, useState } from "react"
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion"

import clsx from "clsx"

const images = [
  {
    id: 1,
    url: "https://images.unsplash.com/5/unsplash-kitsune-4.jpg?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=200&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=50827fd8476bfdffe6e04bc9ae0b8c02",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    url: "https://images.unsplash.com/5/unsplash-kitsune-4.jpg?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=200&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=50827fd8476bfdffe6e04bc9ae0b8c02",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    url: "https://images.unsplash.com/5/unsplash-kitsune-4.jpg?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=200&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=50827fd8476bfdffe6e04bc9ae0b8c02",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    url: "https://images.unsplash.com/5/unsplash-kitsune-4.jpg?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=200&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=50827fd8476bfdffe6e04bc9ae0b8c02",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    url: "https://images.unsplash.com/5/unsplash-kitsune-4.jpg?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=200&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=50827fd8476bfdffe6e04bc9ae0b8c02",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    url: "https://images.unsplash.com/5/unsplash-kitsune-4.jpg?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=200&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=50827fd8476bfdffe6e04bc9ae0b8c02",
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    url: "https://images.unsplash.com/5/unsplash-kitsune-4.jpg?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=200&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=50827fd8476bfdffe6e04bc9ae0b8c02",
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    url: "https://images.unsplash.com/5/unsplash-kitsune-4.jpg?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=200&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=50827fd8476bfdffe6e04bc9ae0b8c02",
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    url: "https://images.unsplash.com/5/unsplash-kitsune-4.jpg?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=200&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=50827fd8476bfdffe6e04bc9ae0b8c02",
  },
]

const backdropAnim = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    transition: {
      duration: 0.16,
    },
  },
  visible: {
    opacity: 0.8,
    transition: {
      delay: 0.04,
      duration: 0.2,
    },
  },
}

const Gallery = () => {
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState<boolean | number>(false)

  const handleClose = useCallback(() => {
    setSelectedId(false)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="w-[1300px]"> // Try changing this to w-auto and see that it works, but then scroll snap is disabled..
      <ul className="h-[620px] grid grid-rows-2 grid-flow-col gap-3 snap-x snap-mandatory overflow-x-scroll">
        {images.map((image, index) => (
          <motion.li
            key={image.id}
            className="relative first:row-span-2 snap-start w-[425px]"
            onClick={() => selectedId === false && setSelectedId(index)}
          >
            <motion.div
              className="h-full w-full"
              layoutId={`placeholder-${index}`}
            >
              <Image src={image.url} layout="fill" />
            </motion.div>
          </motion.li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <AnimatePresence>
        {selectedId !== false && (
          <>
            <motion.div className="fixed h-full w-1/3 mx-auto top-0 inset-x-0 z-40 py-10">
              <motion.div
                className="relative w-full h-full"
                onClick={handleClose}
              >
                <motion.div
                  key={`popup-${selectedId}`}
                  className={clsx(
                    "absolute inset-x-0 inset-y-0",
                    selectedId == 0 ? "aspect-[20/30]" : "aspect-[10/10]"
                  )}
                  layoutId={`placeholder-${selectedId}`}
                >
                  <Image src={images[selectedId].url} layout="fill" />
                </motion.div>
              </motion.div>
            </motion.div>
            <motion.div
              className="fixed inset-x-0 inset-y-0 bg-black z-30 bg-opacity-20"
              key="backdrop"
              onClick={handleClose}
              variants={backdropAnim}
              initial="hidden"
              exit="hidden"
              animate="visible"
            />
          </>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Gallery
```